# Почему, написав MainActivity.this, мы получаем Context из класса, который наследуется от Activity?

Tags: java, android

`Context` – это объект, который предоставляет доступ к базовым функциям приложения: доступ к ресурсам, к файловой системе, вызов активности и т.д. `Activity` является подклассом Context, поэтому в коде мы можем использовать её как `ИмяАктивности`.`this` (напр. `MainActivity.this`), или укороченную запись this.
  `This` указывает на текущий экземпляр, почему в этом случае `this` указывает на класс родителя?

Это какая то специфика андроида, что какой то метод требует доступ к методам contex'a и написав this именно в этом случае , я указываю что у этого класса в котором я нахожусь , есть в родителях Context ?

Comment: MainActivity.this - это обращение к экземпляру MainActivity из его внутреннего класса. Просто this - обращение к тому же экземпляру MainActivity из этой активности за пределами внутренних классов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы сами написали - `Activity` является потомком `Context`-а.

А если один класс наследуется от другого, то он содержит все те же методы, что и класс-родитель, и может содержать свои методы, а также переопределять методы родителя.

В том случае, если вам куда-то нужно передать контекст, или вообще экземпляр какого-то родительского класса, вы можете передать любого потомка этого класса (в данном случае - активити потомок контекста), и ошибок не будет, потому что активити это расширение контекста, оно может иметь какие-то свои методы, или переопределять методы родителя, которые в любом случае будут содержаться в классе-потомке.

Посмотрим на пример:

У вас есть класс `Animal`, от него наследуется класс `Man`. Вам где-то нужно реализовать метод, работающий с классом `Cat`, нужны только методы этого класса. У вас есть наследник `Cat`, который реализует все эти методы, может иметь что-то своё или переопределять методы родителя. Вполне логично, что вызывая себя (`this`) ваш `Cat` сможет использовать любые методы `Animal`-a, а если где-то, например, в другом классе в каком-то методе нужны способности `Animal`-а, то можно передать туда экземпляр `Cat`-а, который тоже является `Animal`-ом, и всё будет хорошо, потому что нужные методы у него будут.

В вашем вопросе всё аналогично:

> почему в этом случае this указывает на класс родителя?

`this` указывает на экземпляр активити, а не на своих многочисленных предков, но `this` можно передавать в те методы, в которых требуются классы-родители.

> какой-то метод требует доступ к методам `Context`'a и написав `this` именно в этом случае, я указываю что у этого класса, в котором я нахожусь, есть в родителях `Context`

Как я уже выше написал, ваш `this` по цепочке наследуется от кучи классов, имплементирует кучу интерфейсов, и в любой методе, где требуется какой-то из этих классов/интерфейсов, можно передать экземпляр вашего активити.

Вы как-то всё не так изначально поняли, почитайте про наследование (один из трех основных принципов ООП). Это не специфика андроида или языка в частности, это принцип ООП.

Comment: дополните пожалуйста. Когда в каком то классе мне нужен контекст, я из класса наследуемого от активити могу передать this и тут будут переданы все методы всех классов от которого я наследуюсь. Но мне нужно только доступ к файловой системе например. Не умнее в классе из которого я хотел передать this , создать экземпляр Context context и передавать его? или я не смогу его инициализировать так чтобы мог передать только методы Context

Comment: @Turalllb вам где-то нужен только контекст - поставьте входным параметром в этот метод контекст и передавайте this туда, и уже там будет доступен только контекст. Ваш this скастится к контексту и будут доступны только его методы

Comment: шикааарно) спасибо, это наверно неявное приведение типов произойдет?